# how to access a database when the access is restricted to a particular place

Tags: sql, networking, network-programming

There is a student database in Some College.Some Organization wants to access it from their headquarters.

But access is restricted within college only.

Is it possible for you to extract data?

How and what SQL queries and functions for the above?

in network programming in can do by connecting via tcp r udp and extracting information but is t possible if the databasae is large?

how can we do using sql function

Comment: i did  something in network programming

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to dump the data and reimport it into your own database. Depends on how big the data is you require. At work I have similar problems and I have to do the same somteimes.

If your admin dumps the data for you, then it is easier. You can also export it with sql commands, but how depends on which database you are using. When you dump it to CSV format, you can import it into a SQLIte datbase easily (or others like MySQL etc.), if you don't have a local DB version of your own database.

An alternative is to export the data yourself into a CSV. How to do this depends on the DB that you use and you didn't mention it. Under Oracle you can use the `set` and `spool` command to achieve this.

Comment: the Databaseadmin of "student database in Some College" needs to export the data into a file. that file needs to be moved to "Some Organization". There the file needs to be imported into some database. Then it can be accessed. CSV is a possible format for such a file.